# Unable to type in JTextField

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I am having one small issue with JTextField on Japanese RHEL5 Machine that user is not able to type anything in it, I am creating it using following syntax

```
Container c = getContentPane();
c.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints(0, 0, 1, 1, 0.0, 0.0,
GridBagConstraints.EAST, GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(5, 5, 10, 0), 0, 0);

c.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
JTextField txtName = new JTextField(10);
txtName.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            disableBtn();
        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
    c.add(txtName, gbc);
```

disableBtn() method disables button on dialog if user has not typed anything in above textfield.
And adding it to JPanel using add method, I am using GridBagLayout for this. This issue happens with some JTextField and others are working fine. Also, on my development machine all works good but when I transfer code to Japanese RHEL5 machine, there is issue.

I have faced similar issue with JPasswordField and solved it using following,

```
password.setEchoChar('*');
password.enableInputMethods(true);
```

The machine having problem is having following output of "java -version" command,

```
# java -version
```

```
java version "1.6.0_31"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_31-b04)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 20.6-b01, mixed mode)
```

Which I think is fine. Is there anything which I am missing over here?

Comment: you might want to paste the snippets of code relevant to the `JTextField`s that are not editable.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an **[SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)**.  This should be reproducible in < 20 lines of code.  BTW - *"I am creating it using following syntax

`JTextField field = new JtextField();`"*  No you are not!  That code would not compile (due to wrong case).  Please don't waste the time of people trying to help you, by posting 'something like' the code used.  ***Copy/paste*** whether it is an SSCCE or code snippets.

Comment: Yes I typed it, but there is nothing other than that. I have edited it anyway.

Answer (score 3):

1) your code din't showed what is `c.add(txtName, gbc)`;, there could be most important reason, I think that you pretty ignored request by `@Andrew Thompson`, code posted here isn't SSCCE,

2) don't use [Keylistener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html), because your [JTextComponent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html) must have `setFocusable()`, I miss this code line, for Swing `JComponents` use [KeyBindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

3) for listenening into [JTextComponents](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html) use only [DocumentListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html)

Comment: Added some more code, which I thought might not be necessary. Are you sure it is issue of KeyListner, because it comes into picture only when key is typed, in my case key is not at all get typed and that also on japanese machine where I dont have access. Could you please elaborate more on issue of KeyListner over DocumentListener.

Comment: right your thought was correct, this code talking about nothing, ContentPane is from JFrame, JDialog, JWindow, did you really want to help on this forum, why we must ask you for help, code that you posted here talking about 10pct from potential issues that exist around ...

Comment: please have a look at my question neatly, it has statement about Dialog right after the code I posted. If you want to help then help rather than criticizing. \m/

Comment: JDialog, Dialog or dialog ???, `If you want to help then help rather than criticizing. \m/`, there are lots of pages where you can ask for support against payment, we are there only voulunters without VPN or RDP to your computer, you asked for help, then you have accepting our rulles, otherwise answers are as you can see, for correct answer to your question I missed everything that we mentioned in ours comments

Comment: Good I must say thanks for your support, it is JDialog. Now let me know your correct answer.

Comment: 1) remove KeyListener, 2) is there another Top-Level Container, 3) has JDialog own parent, 4) is dialog created on `Initial Thread` or from some of `Swing Listener`, 5) all parts/JComponents of JDialog are visible on both Native OS's

Comment: 1. I will try removing it, 2. In JDialog is modal dialog and getting shown on top of JFrame, 3. I haven't defined any parent for JDialog exlplicitely. 4. Dialog is directly getting opened on button click of background JFrame. 5. All Parts of JDialog are visible on both native OS's

Comment: rest of my question are most important, tha usage of DocumentListener, because you have got issue with Focus SubSystem, each of Native OS have got different ...